# the 'rebuke-tochacha' tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

The [rebuke-tochacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebuke-tochacha) tag, q.v., currently has four questions:

- two are about rebuking one's fellow Jew when he sins,
- [one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16492/170) is about a verse in the *tochacha* in *parashas B'chukosay* (and also has the [bechukosai](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bechukosai) tag), and
- [the last](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18119) is about a verse in the Torah reading of 9 *Av*, in *Vaeschanan* (and also has the [vaeschanan](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vaeschanan) tag).

I think that the same tag should not be used for all these uses. I propose that:

- the [rebuke-tochacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebuke-tochacha) tag be renamed [rebuke-hochacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebuke-hochacha) (to avoid confusion with the *tochacha* portions of the Torah) and be for questions about rebuking one's fellow who sins,
- the question about a verse in *B'chukosay* have a new tag for the *tochachos* found in the Torah (or not: I personally don't think it needs one), and
- the question about a verse in *Vaeschanan* be detagged because that part of the Torah is not usually referred to as *tochacha*.

I welcome alternative solutions in answers, including "I like the status quo"; I also welcome suggestions for the new *tochachos*-in-the-Torah tag if any.

Answer (score 1):

I propose keeping and renaming it (as per the question, unless a better suggestion comes along), removing it from the latter two questions, and not replacing it in the case of the B'chukotai question.  I think we already have the pattern that while some specific incidents/passages get their own tags (e.g. gan-eden), not all do (e.g. there's nothing for Kayin and Hevel) and it's always safe to go straight to the containing parsha.